How to connect the domparser object in Googlescript?
I'm trying to parse a page in a Googlescript script in order to get a list of tables at
"https://stihi.ru/readers.html?vlassoff&start=0"
But the script gives an error
ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
Gemini told me

The error ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined occurs when you try to use the DOMParser object but it is not available in the current environment. This can happen for a few reasons:
You are trying to use DOMParser in a Google Apps Script that is not running in a web context. For example, you cannot use DOMParser in a script that is running in the Sheets editor.
Here are some ways to fix the error ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined:
If you are trying to use DOMParser in a Google Apps Script:
You can make sure that your script is running in a web context by using the HtmlService class. For example, you can create a web app and then call your script from the web app.

My code:
function countTablesInHTMLDoc(url) {
  var htmlString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  var tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
  var tableCount = tables.length;
  return tableCount;
}

function exampleUsage() {

  var url = "https://stihi.ru/readers.html?vlassoff&start=0";
  var tableCount = countTablesInHTMLDoc(url);
  Logger.log("Количество таблиц в документе по ссылке " + url + ": " + tableCount);
}


What Is the point to post what Gemini toldo you?

Try using a webapp or perhaps  even a dialog.

“DOMParser” is not a pre-integrated Apps Script class. For a comprehensive description of all available Apps Script classes, please check this Google Developers article.
As a workaround, you can try using the string split method in order to compute the number of times the “table” element occurs in the raw HTML string.
Please find the code below:
function myFunction() {
   
   var htmlString = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stihi.ru/readers.html?vlassoff&start=0").getContentText()
   
   let numberOfTables = htmlString.split("</table").length - 1;

   console.log(numberOfTables);

}

Here the split method will break the string at each iteration of the end tag of the table and will create an array with each of those strings, as such we can use length -1 to find the number of occurrences of this string.

Will the script you provided count nested tables?

I tried this with the URL you had provided, and it also counted the nested table elements. I then manually tested this with the same link, and the number of tables was the same.

The question was to get a list of tables, not a number of tables. Do you understand the difference?
